# wexpect and finding expected prompts

Tags: python-3.7, wexpect

In python, I am trying to automate the execution of an exe. There are several things that need to be done within a GUI that is popped open when running the exe mannualy. My first issue is trying to determine what prompts to send using wexpect. I have successfully created a child that pops open the GUI.

What are the lines i need to place after the spawning of the child to find out what the prompts are?

```
def inspect_exe(self):
# Create a pexpect REPL session
self.child = wexpect.spawn(self.exe_path)
# Enter interactive mode
self.child.read()
```